# Why does JTable always trigger ListSelectionListener twice?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jtable

Is it normal that any changes to the selected row of the `JTable` will trigger the added `ListSelectionListener` twice?

Is it possible that the `ListSelectionListener` can be triggered only once?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Look at the event that is passed to your listener, specifically

```
ListSelectionEvent.getValueIsAdjusting()
```

perform whatever ops you want to do when this returns false.

Comment: Can u plz give a few more detailed ans @MeBigFatGuy

Comment: In fact you pass twice thru the ListSelectionEvent, the first time getValueIsAdjusting() is true and you get the index of the selection with getSelectedIndex(), the second time getValueIsAdjusting() is false and you do what your program wants with this selection, if you call again getSelectedIndex() in this second pass, you get getSelectedIndex() == -1.

Answer (score 5):

`ListSelectionEvent.getValueIsAdjusting()` will work as commented by @MeBigFatGuy.

Similar example:

```
if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
    String selectedData = null;

    int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
    int selectedColumns = table.getSelectedColumn();

    for (int i = 0; i <= selectedRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= selectedColumns; j++) {
            selectedData = (String) table.getValueAt(selectedRow, selectedColumns);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Selected: " + selectedData);
}
```

it'll be triggered just once.